# Creating a new Array from an existing Array (php)

Tags: php, arrays

Okay I'm quite experienced with C# but am very new with PHP so please bear with me.

I have an existing array that looks a bit like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [author] => Gavin
        [weighting] => 2743
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [author] => Bob
        [weighting] => 2546
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [author] => Gavin
        [weighting] => 2227
    )
)
```

Now what I want to do is loop through that and end up with a new array that has 2 keys (`Gavin` and `Bob`) and `Bob`'s value is `2546` while `Gavin`'s is `4970`.

Right now I have this which nearly works but the last author gets a duplicate value and I can't sort it?

```
if (array_key_exists($authorName, $Authors)) {
    foreach ($Authors as $key_name => &$key_value) {
        if ($key_name == $authorName)
        {
                $key_value = $key_value + $weight;
        }
    }
}
else {
    $Authors[$authorName] = $weight;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
$newarray = array();
foreach($yourarray as $a) {
    //create array if not created
    if(!isset($newarray[$a['author']])) {
        $newarray[$a['author']] = 0;
    }
    //put value in array
    $newarray[$a['author']] += $a['weighting'];
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error 'Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array' on the line where I am putting the value into the array?

Answer (score 0):

```
$Authors = array();

foreach($array as $entry) {
    if ( array_key_exists($entry['author'], $Authors) ) {
        $Authors[ $entry['author'] ] += $entry['weighting'];
    } else {
        $Authors[ $entry['author'] ] = $entry['weighting'];
    }
}
```

See it here in action: http://codepad.viper-7.com/LUx1r5

Comment: that's a very nice link to test PHP thanks.. I accepted the one that I understood the best but yes this also worked perfectly